# Powershell get presence of Azure user

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, office365, microsoft-teams

A year ago I created a script that outputs the presence of a SkypeFB user. To do that I used the `Microsoft.Lync.Model.dll` with this:

```
$client = [Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient]::GetClient()
$contact = $client.ContactManager.GetContactByUri("spiderman@marvel.com")
$availabilityId = $contact.GetContactInformation("Availability")
$activity = $contact.GetContactInformation("Activity")
```

Since all our employees **don't use Skype anymore** it's not needed anymore. They **use MS Teams now**. Is there any way I can output the exact same information?
What I tried:

```
Install-Module AzureAD
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $credential
Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "spiderman@marvel.com"
```

This works (I get information about the Azure AD user), but I couldn't find any status, availability/activity or presence.
Does anyone know? If you need any further information, just ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We plan to expose presence via Microsoft Graph APIs, hopefully by the end of the year, but we don’t have any more specific plans to share at this time.

It’s a very popular request though. In the meantime there’s unfortunately no way to get or set user presence in Teams.

Comment: Thank you. Where would I be able to see it when it's released?